# How to get unread articles from the past hour using google reader api

Tags: google-reader

I m able to get 20 unread articles using this
http://www.google.com/reader/atom/user/[userid]/state/com.google/reading-list?n=20'

How do I get all unread articles within the past 1hour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.google.com/reader/atom/user/[userid]/state/com.google/reading-list?n=1000&ot=[current epoch time - 3600]&r=n&xt=user/-/state/com.google/read

&r=n desc order, &r=o asc order

Comment: What if the feed is not from google reader (Ex http://feeds.nytimes.com/nyt/rss/HomePage) How do I get the articles from the past hour? I DONT want to download the entire feed to my iphone app since it takes too long.

Comment: http ://www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/http ://feeds.nytimes.com/nyt/rss/HomePage? n=100&r=n&ot=[current epoch time - 3600]
      
shoul only give you the last hour if the &ot is sent correctly.  sorry had to put some spaces in there, just remove any space from the url above.

Comment: I subscribe to 2 different feeds using google reader (feeds.nytimes.com/nyt/rss/HomePage and feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch). How do I get the 50 unread articles from feeds.nytimes.com/nyt/rss/HomePage and 50 unread articles from feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch? In your code above I didnt see any mention of my userid.

Comment: your user id would replace [userid] in the url.  it's not your login id it's the userId when you look from this url, https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/user-info

Comment: I m sorry but in the code you gave (http ://www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/http://feeds.nytimes.com/nyt/rss/HomePage?n=100)  there is no mention of [userid]